# sqlite locking and SQLITE_BUSY troubleshooting

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am using sqlite in iOS and I see that one of my queries is taking a long time to return (several seconds). I added a busy handler and I see it is being called for SQLITE_BUSY condition. However I cannot figure out what the database is doing to be busy at that time. I also see that internally Lock is being called but that is returning SQLITE_BUSY.

I am using multiple threads to access the DB but all other threads operations have returned.

How can I troubleshoot to figure out why I am getting SQLITE_BUSY?

Comment: Have you tried enabling error logging? http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/log.html

Comment: *Some* thread (or other process) still has the file locked.

Comment: The logging mentioned by NuSkooler is only if I want to add my own logging, and I already have a bunch of logging which isn't helping much. Is there any way to turn on built in logging to show which queries are running?

Comment: Regarding CL's comment: how I can check who has the file locked?

Comment: for every thread you need a new db-connection. to handle this you could use a method that gives you a connection based on the thread you are in. i you are still looking for an answer i can provide more information.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this problem in Deno as well (ts/js). I have a few scripts that use the db in addition to the app.js file. I keep getting busy errors. but I can't find anything about how to add a "busy handler"